# Broken content in stackoverflow.blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

[Link](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/12/improvements-to-badge-system/) to the page that contains this:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: seems the same on desktop browsers. I wonder *when* it broke

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Same wonder *when*. Interested about the migration of the images that should have been there.

Comment: Looks like they migrated it again from WordPress to their own code, in which case it's totally expected many things broke. /cc @Journeyman

Comment: @ShadowWizard BTW, what does `/cc` mean?

Comment: @iDebug https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_copy (so when talking with someone, it's used to notify someone else.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. We migrated a few times between Wordpress and Jekyll over the years, which likely caused these changes. I'll fix them shortly.

Comment: We can also replace that. To be fair, a lot of our very old blog content (earlier than 2015) may have broken elements from the switch. We will slowly fix these, but since the posts are older, other things will likely take priority. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @Rachel many old blog posts are linked from important places e,g, Help Center, so think it should get some priority.

Comment: I agree. The team that was responsible for this is no longer here, hence a little craziness. Please continue pointing out the important ones to us and we will get them fixed!

Comment: @Rachel Guess how I navigated to this page? From the FAQ. What *Shadow Wizard* said is true: they're linked from important places.

Comment: Noted! I can prioritize fixing those ones first (ones being linked to from FAQ or other Help pages).